# What free software exists to view molecule pictures within a file explorer?

Tags: software, molecular-structure

I am testing my small api library that generates lots of chemical files such as MOL and SDF. I was wondering if there is a software that can show me the pictures of chemical structures inside each file so that I don't have to open each of these separately. would prefer something free for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this tool named [thumbfish](http://abhimanyusirohi.github.io/ThumbFish) (Windows only). It can display thumbnails for variety of formats and is free

Comment: I wish thumbfish could also handle *.cif and *.mrv files.

Comment: @andselisk you should try to convert them with free openbabel software

Answer (score 5):

On the Mac, there's [ChemSpotlight](http://chemspotlight.openmolecules.net). The most recent version includes a QuickLook component that will allow previews of most molecule files, including interactive 3D depictions using HTML/JavaScript.

You can also batch generate previews of MDL, SDF, etc. using [Open Babel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FileFormats/SVG_2D_depiction.html#svg-2d-depiction) to export previews to SVG or PNG formats.

Answer (score 4):

What about [JMol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net) ?

It opens .Mol and a slew of other formats in Java which is fairly widely compatible. Open-source too.

Comment: jMol has an application that can show structure pictures but then I have to open each of my files to view them. I am looking for something that will generate a thumbnail for my structures.

Comment: JMol is scriptable, and it can generate image files, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Free Maestro or Maestro Academics](https://www.schrodinger.com/freemaestro), but you have to read [EULA](https://www.schrodinger.com/maestro-academic-eula) before, maybe you are going to use it for commercial purposes.
This is software for creation and opening of the databases, can read almost all formats. And also has 2d drawing tool and is cross-platform.